# Malloc allocation for strings

Tags: c, malloc

Still a beginner trying to grasp memory allocation. In the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct key_value
{
    int key;
    char *value;
} key_value;

int main(void)
{
    int keys = 2;
    key_value *kv = malloc(sizeof(key_value) * keys);

    kv[0].key = 1;
    kv[0].value = "Value of Key 1";

    kv[1].key = 2;
    kv[1].value = "Value of Key 2";

    printf("Key = %d\nKey value = %s\n", kv[0].key, kv[0].value);
    printf("Key = %d\nKey value = %s\n", kv[1].key, kv[1].value);


    free(kv);
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Are values for .key & .value stored in the allocation by malloc? If yes, how many characters are initialized by malloc for the value of *value since it's a string that hasn't been set a size? If no, where are the .key & .value stored (I'm guessing that malloc just holds the pointer to these value pairs instead)?
2. Is it good practice to specify the max size of an array (i.e. char value[n]) when putting them in structs or is this optional to the coder?

Thank you in advanced. Moving from python to c is a lot of unlearning but I'm pretty excited about learning c! :P

Comment: Your `value` fields are assigned with string literals, which are allocated statically. In general it is not a good way to allocate strings within dynamic data structures. Instead you should `malloc` them to the desired size (or just make constant size arrays part of the structure) and `strcpy` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure will always have the same size : `sizeof (int) + sizeof(char *)` because your struct only stores the address of `value`. If you want to allocate memory for your string you will have to malloc `kv[n].value`.

Comment: I've seen some sample codes that utilize _strdup_.. I'm guessing that is one of the methods for allocating space for the string. If doing this then each `kv[n].value` would need to be freed separately before freeing the `kv`, yes?

Also, would it be right to say that the code attached to my question stores the address of `value` to the string value in the stack if no malloc is done for the string value?

Comment: @SureshKumar strdup uses malloc [man strdup](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)
And yes you will need to free separately every single space you malloced, I recommend doing a function for that (freeing value pointer then freeing struct)
Also constants are not stored in the stack, they have a special space. If you try to write anything to that address you will get a segmentation fault.